# Insert FLV video in latex document

Tags: video, latex, include, media

I'm trying to insert a flv video in a latex document. I've tried the following :

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{animation/animation1.flv}
\caption{My animation}
\label{Anim1}
\end{figure}
```

But it's not working at all ! Does anyone know how to do this ? I would avoid to convert the video because I don't know what kind of codec the reader would have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `media9.sty`, available from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/media9/). You might need to slightly modify the `.sty` to tell it that `.flv` is also a movie file.

> I would avoid to convert the video because I don't know what kind of codec the reader would have.

Well, if you care about the setup of the reader, you can't even assume that the video embedded in the pdf to work. It's not well supported except Adobe Reader. Even Adobe Reader on Linux doesn't support it.

So, do ask the reader which PC environment s/he uses, and prepare and test the file accordingly.

Comment: I didn't know that some PDF reader do not support this feature. From you point of view, what seems to be the best solution to include this video in order to maximize the reader compatibility (taking into account multiple os and multiple pdf reader as you said before)? MP4 ?

Comment: If you embed the video to PDF, you just have to ask the reader to use Windows or Mac, and use the latest Adobe Reader. (Note many Mac users don't use Adobe Reader; the Preview.app which comes with OS X is very good for static PDFs.) I don't know what's natively supported by the Adobe Reader itself, but `.flv` and `.mp4` would be a safe bet. Otherwise, Adobe Reader will use the platform's media player to play it.

The most portable way would be to put the video to Youtube, and put a clickable link in the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `\includegraphics` for that. This command is for images only. [This page](http://www.uoregon.edu/~noeckel/PDFmovie.html) offers a package, which allows you to include videos within the generated document. The code would then look like this (copied from the linked page):

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \includemovie[
     poster,
     text={\small(Loading Circle-m-increase3.mp4)}
  ]{6cm}{6cm}{Circle-m-increase3.mp4}
\end{figure}
```